# Selenium Click() not always working in chrome or firefox browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, automated-tests

I am Testing my Office Admin Site and in that there is a sidebar which contains multiple options but the click method is not working, I want to click on the employee link but its not clicking, its working fine till 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/div/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]")).click();`

but after that the click method is not working Please help
[ScreenShot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gd3j.png)

My Code:

```
        WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http:******");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Submit']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-collapse']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-collapse']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/div/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Did you try adding a wait before clicking on 'Employee'. Also, please share detailed error report of what happens when you try to click on 'Employee'

Comment: adding wait is working some times but not always

Comment: An optimal wait needs to be added to the test so that it works everytime. You can find that by running it multiple times and see which minimum wait value works evrytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding implicit wait after driver initialization

```
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: its working but not always, some times its runs, some time it dosen't why ?

Comment: I have to Continuesly change the SECONDS like 10, then 5, then 10 again in order to run the script WHY ???

Comment: you can set some time like 10 or 15 seconds. implicit wait lets selenium wait for element to present till that time. If found earlier it will continue with steps or reports failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(tester, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span[1]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but adding implicit wait has worked perfectly for me.